# Weird problems with CSS position:absolute

Tags: css, positioning, css-position

I am having some really weird problems with `position:absolute`. I have set the main title of [my webpage](http://inventaweb.net/davies/) to be position absolute, but when I resize the window, the text moves around. The really weird thing is that the tagline (the Bible verse) is also `position:absolute`, but it isn't having any problems. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing your screen resolution is 1920x1080? Looks like you've gone and positioned the element relative to the window, which only works if the window is that size.

Try removing the `position: absolute` and the `right` properties, and using `float:right` instead of `float:left`.

As for the tagline element, you made it `position: relative` and `float: right`. `position: relative`, here, does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Thanks! That worked. My resolution is 1280x1080. So what was happening?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest adding the `position: relative` to the `#logoWrapper`:

```
#logoWrapper {
    ...
    position: relative;
    ...
}
```

Thus its children with `position: absolute` will be positioned relatively to the `#logoWrapper`, not the `body`, as Kolink said.